# Packaging with pyproject.toml that will include other multi level directories

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have spent two full days trying to figure this out with no success. I have a python project that I want to package. That is the easy part. The part I can't figure out is how to copy other multilevel folders into the package.

I am trying to get the *myproj* as a package with the *dosomething.py* but also have the *algorithms* and *configs* folders in there entirety (folder structure and all files included).

Project structure:

```
 - myproj
     - src
         - myproj
             - dosomething.py
     - tests
         - test_do_something.py
     - algorithms
         - Type1
             - algorithm1
                 - eval.py
                 - hyperparameters.yml
                 - a bunch of other folders and files
             - algorithm2
                 - eval.py
                 - hyperparameters.yml
                 - a bunch of other folders and files
         - Type2
             - algorithm3
                 - eval.py
                 - hyperparameters.yml
                 - a bunch of other folders and files
             - algorithm4
                 - eval.py
                 - hyperparameters.yml
                 - a bunch of other folders and files
     - configs
         - type1.yml
         - type2.yml
     - pyproject.toml
     - mypy.ini
     - tox.ini
     - run-mypy
```

Contents of pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "myproj"
version = "0.0.1"
readme = "README.md"
dependencies = [
    "numpy >= 1.26.4",
    ]

[project.urls]
repository = "https://gitlab.com/somerepo

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "tox",
    "pytest",
    "pytest-sugar",
    "pytest-cov",
    "black",
    "flake8",
    "flake8-docstrings",
    "mypy",
    "pre-commit",
    "sphinx",
    "sphinx-rtd-theme"
]
```

After doing a pip install in a new conda env, I am looking for the following:

```
- env/test_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
    - myproj
        - algorithms and everything under it
        - configs and everything under it
        - dosomething.py
```

I have tried MANIFEST.in, I have tried everything on this page: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

I figure this would be trivial to copy folders and files in the entirety into a package folder but I am stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Files that need to be included in the wheel (and the sdist) and need to be installed, have to be inside a sub-directory of the top-level import package. So in your case, everything you want to be installed should be in `src/myproj` (or in sub-directories of it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give that a try again. 
The best I was able to do was to get it to only give the directories that had python files in them, not .yml, not .json. Beacuse of this alot of files and folders were missing from the algorithms directory. I need everything copied in there as data, not python modules/subpackages etc.

Comment: As far as I know, when you want to package, only the things under `src/myproj` would be packaged. You can exclude something in it, but you can't include something outside it.
If you really don't want to put your data/config files into your package, especially you may need to modify them, I think using a `.env` file and [`python-dotenv`](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) would be a good choice.
Last, I suggest you to use [`pdm`](https://pdm-project.org/latest/) to manage your project. It is more modern and easy to use than `setuptools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 standard directory structures automatically supported by `setuptools` without extra configuration:

1. The vanilla [`src-layout`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout): in summary, whatever you put ***inside*** the `src` directory will be copied to `site-packages` during the installation.
2. The vanilla [`flat-layout`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout): in summary, there is a single folder directly inside the your project root (named after the "import-name" you want your users to use) that will itself be copied to `site-packages` during the installation.

Note that in both cases a part of the directory structure in the source-code is mimicked inside `site-packages`.

In your example, it seems that your want to cherry-pick different parts of your source-code and reassemble them in a different directory structure inside `site-packages` (with no identical counterpart in the source-code). This is a non-trivial customisation that requires extra configuration to happen:

1. You need to explicitly set [`tool.setuptools.packages`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-packages), since the auto-discovery cannot handle custom project layouts. Probably something like (untested, may require adjustments):

   ```ini
   [tool.setuptools]
   packages = ["myproj", "myproj.algorithms", "myproj.configs", ...]
   ```

   You need to write ***all*** nested packages. Also please note that Python all folders are considered packages and can be imported. Even if they don't contain a `__init__.py`.
2. You need to set [`tool.setuptools.package-dir`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-package-dir) to "remap"/"reassemble" your files into the custom structure. Probably something like (untested, may require adjustments):

   ```ini
   [tool.setuptools.package-dir]
   myproj = "src/myproj"
   myproj.algorithms = "algorithms"
   myproj.configs = "configs"
   ```
3. (Optional) If you want to avoid having to write `MANIFEST.in`, you can also add [`tool.setuptools.package-data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-package-data) (untested, may require adjustments):

   ```ini
   [tool.setuptools.package-data]
   "" = ["*.yml", ...]
   ```

   Here `""` (empty string` is a special value that means "any package").

This can be quite tedious (and also require changes in `pyproject.toml` every time you create a new folder). That is why most of the people tend to go with "convention over configuration" and just re-structure their project folders in a way that matches either the vanilla `src-layout` or `flat-layout`.